# req.body empty when making a call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, body-parser

I built a server to make some Graphql mutations in a shopify store, it has already work, but now when I want to pass the variables dynamically from a client it gets the body empty even though the payload has the object I'm sending in the network tab, here is my server and call, could anyone help?

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express')
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: shopName
  apiKey: apiKey
  password: password
});

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/create-shipping-profile', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  try{
    const variables = await req.body.profile
    const query = `mutation deliveryProfileCreate($profile: DeliveryProfileInput!) {
      deliveryProfileCreate(profile: $profile) {
        profile {
          zoneCountryCount
          name
        }
        userErrors {
          field
          message
        }
      }
    }`;
    shopify
    .graphql(query, variables)
    .then((customers) => console.log(customers))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }

});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And this is the request I made:

```
 async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
      body: data,
    });
    return JSON.parse(response);

  }
  let data = {"profile": {
      "name": "render created",
      "locationGroupsToCreate": [
        {
          "locations": [
            "gid://shopify/Location/76352618802"
          ],
          "zonesToCreate": [
            {
              "countries": [
                {
                  "code": "MX",
                  "includeAllProvinces": true

                }
              ],
              "methodDefinitionsToCreate": [
                {
                  "active": true,
                  "description": "",
                  "name": "Creado desde render",
                  "rateDefinition": {
                    "price": {
                      "amount": "999",
                      "currencyCode": "MXN"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "name": "admin"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  postData("https://deliveryprofiles.onrender.com/create-shipping-profile", data)
      .then((data) => {
        let cart = JSON.parse(data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I expect to get the profiles in the body of my request to pass them to eh graphql mutation but instead I get an empty object.

Comment: `body: data` should be `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I have already tried that and didn't work, is there something else that could be wrong? I the payload in the network tab but it doesn't get to the server.

Comment: I don't know why. Also, you have a problem when processing the response. `fetch()` doesn't return the response text. You need to do `return await response.json();`. See [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json)